# drawing clipping plane and wireframe simultaneously in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, clip, wireframe

I am trying to clip a **3D model** . It works fine with shaded mode but the application crashes when it is in wireframe mode in some devices only. Is there any issue using `glClipPlanef and GL_LINES`?

I am using `glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES, 6*numberOfFaces, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,shortBuffer )` to draw wireframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with glEnable(GL_TEXTURE2D). When it was removed everything works fine.